# Обработка текста c++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции

Выполнить построчную обработку текста.
если выбранный символ встречается впервые удвоить его.
обработку выполнить через функцию.
пользоваться  `string'ом` нельзя.
пример как должен выглядеть код, но к сожалению он не работает.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void str(char*, int&, int, char, char*y, int & h);
int main()
{
    int j, k, i, n, min, ik, in, s, h, u;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    cout << "введите знак который нужно удвоить: ";
    char  m;
    cin >> m;
    char x[100] = { 0 };
    char y[100] = { 0 };
    cout << "вводите текст. стоп знак = $." << endl;
    cin.get(x, 100, '$');
//  cout << x;              вывод массива который ввели

    i = 0; in = 0; ik = 0; s = 0;h = 0;u = 0;
    cout << "модифицированый массив" << endl;
    while (x[i]){
        y[h] = x[i];
        if (x[i] == '\n'){
            ik = h;
            str(x, in, ik, m, y, h);    
            for (int z = in; y[z]; z++){
            cout << y[z];
        }   
            in = h + 1;
        }
        h++;
        i++;    
    }
cout << y;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void str(char*c, int & d, int e, char l, char*y, int&h){
    int in = 0;
    int z = 0;
    h = d;
    for (int j = d; j < e; j++){

        y[h] = c[j];
        if (y[h] == l){
            h++;
            y[h] = l;
            }
        h++;
        }
    y[strlen(y)] = '\n';
}
```

Как сейчас выглядит вывод

```
введите знак который нужно удвоить: a
вводите текст. стоп знак = $.
asd
dsa
aaasss
sssaaa
s
a
$
модифицированый массив


aasd
saa

aasss
s
aaaaaa
s






aasd
saa

aasss
s
aaaaaa
s
```

Как он примерно должен выглядеть

```
введите знак который нужно удвоить: a
вводите текст. стоп знак = $.
asd
dsa
aaasss
sssaaa
s
a
$
модифицированый массив
aasd
dsaa
aaaasss
sssaaaa
s
aa
aasd
dsaa
aaaasss
sssaaaa
s
aa
```

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Не особо помогло